# problema conectar con la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <div id="img"> </div>

  <input type="text" id="introducir">

  <input type="button" id="traducir" value="traducir!">
```

Código PHP

```
<?php

include("conectar.php");

?>

 <div id="traduccion"> <h3> significado: <?php echo $traduccion; ?> </h3> </div>`
 
  <?php

  if(isset($_GET['traducir'])){

    $busqueda =$_GET['introducir'];

    $traduccion =$conex->query("SELECT FROM * traducciones WHERE traduccion LIKE '%$introducir%'");

    while($row = $traduccion->fetch_array()){

      echo $row['traduccion'];
    }
  }

  ?>
```

quiero que me conecte con la base de datos pero me da error. a continuacion, el otro archivo que se supone que da error

```
<?php

$Chost = "localhost";

$Cuser = "root";

$Cpass = "";

$Cdb = "consulta";

$conex =new mysqli($Chost,$Cuser,$Cpass,$Cdb);

  if($conex->connect_errno){

    die("ha ocurrido un error")
}
?>
```

me dice que tengo un error en la linea 11 osea, asi,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "}" in
> C:\Users\Yasmin\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\traductor argentino\conectar.php
> on line 11

Comment: Debes terminar la sentencia die con punto y coma

Comment: siiiiii, me di cuenta al toque, gracias. igual ahora no me reconoce la variable $traduccion y no se porque :c

Comment: Está mal escrita la query, es: `SELECT * FROM...`.

Comment: joya, tenes razon, pero me sigue sin reconocer la variable :'v perdon que los joda chicos. no me deja publicar otra pregunta por que pasaron menos de minutos.